# JavaScript Recursion function is not working

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm working on a game project. I need a help with one of my function. I need to find random variable from array with specific ID. Here is my function.

```
function randomPick(id,y){   // dots = array of 10 objects, each has id (farm or barrack );
    console.log('number '+y)
    if ( id == dots[y].id ){
        return dots[y]
    } else{
        randomPick(id,y-1);
    }
}
```

My problem is, when the function didn't find the match on first try, it runs over again with lower index till it finds the matching dot. But it always return undefined when it runs more then once.

Thanks for answers :)

Comment: You are missing `return` before `randomPick`

Comment: @Rajesh Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need another [`return` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return).

```
return randomPick(id, y - 1);
// ^^^
```

I suggest to insert another check, if `y` is smaller than zero.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add a second `return` statement.

Also note that you can shorten your logic using [the ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) (`condition ? valueIfTrue : valueOtherwise`), which gives you a bit more room to check that `y` is within the bounds of your array.

```js
var dots = [
  { id: 'farm' }, 
  { id: 'barrack' },
  { id: 'farm' }, 
  { id: 'barrack' },
  { id: 'farm' }, 
  { id: 'barrack' },
  { id: 'farm' }, 
  { id: 'barrack' },
  { id: 'farm' }, 
  { id: 'barrack' }
]

function randomPick(id, y) {
  console.log('y = ' + y)
  
  if (y < 0 || y >= dots.length) return null
  
  return id == dots[y].id) ? dots[y] : randomPick(id, y - 1)
}

console.log(randomPick('farm', 5))
```

Comment: I am aware -- it's hard to know when the posts are only 39 seconds apart.

Comment: My apologies. Didn't see time difference